Unsucessfully trying to install packages on vscode, met with "Python"
No matter what i do i cannot install any packages, i always get the same one word response "Python". How to solve this and finally be able to use python commands?
> python -m pip install numpy  
Python

Is it possible to extract a certain folder containing numpy in the project folder?

Why don't you just use the command python -m pip install numpy ?

if you're doing this in vscode, are you actually using a command line? which version of python is this (python --version)?

the python version i am currently using is 3.12.3, however, when i try using python --version the output is still "Python", just a single word

Apparently using py -m pip install numpy instead solves the problem

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
